# why should this be borrowed?

Tags: rust, reference

From The Book, [listing 13-29](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch13-03-improving-our-io-project.html):

```
pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    contents
        .lines()
        .filter(|line| line.contains(query))
        .collect()
}
```

After an explanation of the above, the reader is invited, "Feel free to make the same change to use iterator methods in the `search_case_insensitive` function as well." Don't mind if I do:

```
pub fn search_case_insensitive<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    contents
        .lines()
        .filter(|line| line.to_lowercase().contains(query.to_lowercase()))
        .collect()
}
```

Nope:

```
error[E0277]: expected a `FnMut<(char,)>` closure, found `String`
   --> src/lib.rs:59:53
    |
59  |         .filter(|line| line.to_lowercase().contains(query.to_lowercase()))
    |                                            -------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an implementor of trait `Pattern<'_>`
    |                                            |
    |                                            required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = note: the trait bound `String: Pattern<'_>` is not satisfied
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Pattern<'_>` for `String`
note: required by a bound in `core::str::<impl str>::contains`
help: consider borrowing here
    |
59  |         .filter(|line| line.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase()))
    |                                                     +
```

Indeed, this compiles and passes the tests from the earlier examples:

```
pub fn search_case_insensitive<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    contents
        .lines()
        .filter(|line| line.to_lowercase().contains(&query.to_lowercase()))
        .collect()
}
```

For that matter, `search` will compile and pass if `query` is borrowed:

```
pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    contents
        .lines()
        .filter(|line| line.contains(&query))
        .collect()
}
```

So why must `query` be borrowed in `search_case_insensitive` but its being a reference (or not)  makes no difference to `search`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`str::contains()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.contains) takes as a predicate generic `P: Pattern`. [The `Pattern` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html) is implemented for `char`, `&char`, `&String`, `&[char]`, `&str`, `&&str`, `[char; N]`, `&[char; N]` and `F where F: FnMut(char) -> bool`. All of those can be passed to `contains()`. However, it is not implemented for `String`. So in `search()`, you pass `&str`. That's fine. If you borrow it, you pass `&&str`, which is also fine. But in `search_case_insensitive()`, if you borrow you pass `&String` and that's fine, but if you don't, you pass `String` which does not implement the `Pattern` trait.

Comment: Thank you, Chayim. I'm missing why, in the broken example, `query` is a `String` in the function body when it's declared `query: &str` in the signature.

Comment: @FranklinEinspruch Because you're not passing `query` but `query.to_lowercase()`, and [`str::to_lowercase()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_lowercase) returns `String`.

Answer (score 2):

The `contains()` method expects as input some type which implements the `Pattern` trait. This trait is implemented for `&str`, but not `String`. This means that `contains()` can be used with an `&str`, but not a `String` (at least not directly).

For the `line.contains(query)` case, `query` is already an `&str`, so we're good.

`query.to_lowercase()` returns a `String` type, so it does not compile. However, `String` can be turned into an `&str` by borrowing, which is why `&query.to_lowercase()` works.

Comment: As for why `line.contains(&query)` works...not sure. `&query` compiles, but `&&query` doesn't. That might be a good separate question! I tried to search for one, but I'm getting nothing but false hits concerning "multiple borrows".

Comment: @ChayimFriedman answers why `&&query` works, `Pattern` is implemented for `&&str`!